# How to determine whether a UNIX timestamp occured 'last week'

Tags: php, unix-timestamp, timestamp

I have a unix timestamp and I want to be able to test whether it occurred earlier than 12:00am Sunday of the current week. Any suggestions?

Comment: Using what programming language?

Comment: @ Matt Ball, php is what I'm trying to do this in. But I'm sure the arithmetic concept is cross-language applicable.

Comment: The naive arithmetic algorithm is easy to implement, and as you guessed language-independent - but wrong. This is because our modern time system has all sorts of complicating features, such as daylight savings time. If you want a 100% correct answer, you need to use an appropriate date library which accounts for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
/**
 * @param  $t  UNIX timestamp
 * @return true iff the given time fell in the previous Sunday->Sunday window
 */
function f($t) {
   $a = strtotime("last Sunday");
   $b = strtotime("-1 week", $a);

   return ($b <= $t && $t < $a);
}

var_dump(f(strtotime("2011-08-12 11:00")));
var_dump(f(strtotime("2011-08-08 11:00")));
var_dump(f(strtotime("2011-08-04 11:00")));
var_dump(f(strtotime("2011-08-01 11:00")));
?>
```

Output:

```
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

---

### [Live demo.](http://codepad.org/qU4dK7XJ)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can generate the timestamp for "12:00am sunday of the current week" using 
the datetime class: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

You should be able to generate a date time object for the target date, then use gettimestamp: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php to convert it into a timestamp.

You can then compare that timestamp to see if it is less than the timestamp you have generated.

Edit: Some code (although not as elegant as Tomalak Geret'kal's)

```
<?php

//Get current year and week
$year = date('Y');
$week = date('W');

//Get date
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$year-W$week-7"));


//Get date with time
$datetime = new DateTime("$date 00:00:00");

//Display the full date and time for a sanity check.
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d h:i:s') . ' = ';

//Convert to timestamp:
$timestamp = $datetime->getTimeStamp();
echo $timestamp;

//Do your comparison here:
if($yourtimestamp < $timestamp){
    return true;
}
```